# Is there a way using SQL to get the value ID that corresponds to the mode ID from the previous row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table to be transformed using SQL:

| ID | message | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value_C | fgh | 2022-08-16 21:00:00 |
| value_B | ksl | 2022-08-16 21:00:00 |
| value_A | cde | 2022-08-16 21:00:00 |
| MODE | B | 2022-08-16 21:00:00 |
| value_C | fgh | 2022-08-16 20:00:00 |
| value_B | fgh | 2022-08-16 20:00:00 |
| value_A | cde | 2022-08-16 20:00:00 |
| MODE | B | 2022-08-16 20:00:00 |
| value_C | xyz | 2022-08-16 19:00:00 |
| value_B | xyz | 2022-08-16 19:00:00 |
| value_A | abc | 2022-08-16 19:00:00 |
| MODE | A | 2022-08-16 19:00:00 |

wanted to do some transformation so it becomes this:

| ID | message | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value_B | ksl | 2022-08-16 21:00:00 |
| MODE | B | 2022-08-16 21:00:00 |
| value_B | fgh | 2022-08-16 20:00:00 |
| MODE | B | 2022-08-16 20:00:00 |
| value_A | abc | 2022-08-16 19:00:00 |
| MODE | A | 2022-08-16 19:00:00 |

However, I couldn't think of a good logic to do this. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: For the first timestamp, there are _three_ distinct messages.  What is the logic for which one we retain as the mode, since there is a three-way tie here?

Comment: The message for value ID is suppose to have a random generated value. The mode ID however is fixed to have the three modes A,B, and C.

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, etc.) ?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `ROW_NUMBER()` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 'MODE' THEN message END) OVER
                  (PARTITION BY time) mode_msg
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, message, time
FROM cte
WHERE ID = 'MODE' OR ID LIKE CONCAT('%_', mode_msg)
ORDER BY time DESC, IF(ID = 'Mode', 1, 0);
```

### Demo

We use pivoting logic to line up the mode letter value with each record from a given timestamp group.  The logic for retaining a record then is either that the `ID` matches the mode, or the `ID` be the mode record itself.

Comment: sorry but what i wanted to do is something like: during the time 21:00:00, if the mode ID at that time is B, the value ID on that hour will just be 'value_b', discarding any other value ID rows at that hour. so, every hour will have 2 IDs which are the mode ID and the value ID. just like the 2nd table in the question.

Comment: @MeitalMeyer Apologies for misunderstanding.  Check the edit above.